# NodeJS 18 breaks DNS resolution of localhost from 127.0.0.1 to ::1

Tags: node.js, localhost, ipv6, monorepo, ipv4

I am working on a NodeJS monorepo which had applications on nodeV16 and I upgraded those to nodeV18. Many of those use `localhost` for communication. With Node 16, the `localhost` used to resolve in `127.0.0.1` but after the upgrade, it started resolving into `::1` and thus breaking the apps at multiple places.

I found over the internet that Node.js 17 switched from resolving host names to IPv4 by default to resolving to the order given by the OS. This was an intended change done in nodejs/node#39987, which nevertheless caused issues in downstream projects, as reported in nodejs/node#40537.

Has anyone faced this in the past and if yes, how did you fix this? I am new to Node and could use some guidance.

We are using linux machines and I am not sure why the order of DNS resolution in the OS is IPv6 first. Not sure if we can change it somehow?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No, the update doesn't "break" DNS resolution.

> I am not sure why the order of DNS resolution in the OS is IPv6 first. Not sure if we can change it somehow?

The order of DNS resolution is IPv6 first because IPv6 is the current-gen internet and IPv4 is an old legacy protocol. Yes, it is possible to change this in the OS (see /etc/gai.conf), but it's usually not a good idea.

If you're contacting `localhost`, this can happen over both IPv4 and IPv6. In order to do that, you need to switch your apps to use "::" instead of "0.0.0.0" which will make it listen on both IPv4 and IPv6. (Or, if they're currently listening on 127.0.0.1, change that to ::1).

If you *really* need the old behaviour back (= you're planning to continue operating applications that do not support current-gen internet) you can try the command line option `--dns-result-order=ipv4first` which will make sure localhost (and other DNS names) resolve to IPv4 again.